# Issue with Corova project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I have Visual Studio 2015 pro version. I have also installed Cordova tools. However, when I created a blank project (using template-> Javascript -> Apache Cordova Apps. While building it shows 17 errors including below one:

```
ERROR: A module failed to load. Please try clearing the Cordova cache by using Tools > Options > Tools for Apache Cordova > Cordova Tools > Clear Cordova Cache. Alternatively, for details on how to reinstall vs-mda, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=522541
```

Have anybody faced this issue earlier? I tried to clear the cache, but that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you share the entire build log with us? Also, can you clarify which version of the Cordova tools you are using? Check Help -> About to see. (Disclosure: I work on the tools for Apache Cordova and my team would like to see the full log).

Comment: I have to uninstall node js. There were two versions one from the foundation and another from joyent. I uninstalled the joyent version and it is working now.

Comment: I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova team at Microsoft. Right now, we're investigating ways to make it easier for developers to recover from build errors in VS. I’m hoping to chat with folks like you who have encountered build errors and reached out to the community for troubleshooting. Customer feedback is the number one way we make product design decisions, so I’d love it if you could make time for a 20min phone call this week or next to talk about how you understand and overcome build issues. rsalva [at] Microsoft [dot] com

Comment: Sure. Let me compile the list of issues. I will email you soon.

Answer (score 1):

I have to uninstall node js. There were two versions one from the foundation and another from joyent. I uninstalled the joyent version and it is working now.